# iOS 8 bug with navigation stack / rotation?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

I have three UIViewControllers: `vc1`, `vc2,` and `vc3` which appear in succession on a `UINavigationController`. `vc1` has the following rotation properties:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL) shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{
    return (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

while `vc2` and `vc3` have the following rotation properties:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL) shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{
    return (toInterfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);

}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return self.presentedViewController.interfaceOrientation;
}
```

While on `vc3` (which is preceded by `vc1` and `vc2` on the navigation stack of course), if the user pushes the restart button, I want it to take them back to vc1:

```
- (void) restartButtonPushed
{
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

This normally works, however if I'm in landscape mode on `vc3`, when I push restart it will take me back to `vc1` in landscape mode. Whereas in < iOS8, `vc1` would be forced into portrait mode. Is this a bug in iOS8? Or possibly was something fixed in iOS8 which exposed how I was doing it the wrong way?

Interesting side note, if I push the restart button while in landscape mode and on `vc2`, it works exactly as it should, `vc1` is forced into portrait mode.

Comment: Something was definitely changed in [iOS8.1](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/iOS81APIDiffs/modules/UIKit.html) in the way `shouldAutorotate` is called. Nothing documented in iOS6 rotation methods (see [Technical QA1688](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1688/_index.html) ) but I have similar issues between 7.1 and 8. Did you work around this ?

Comment: @lazi74 - Nah, still haven't figured our an appropriate work around and still doesn't work for me in 8.1. Might use a DTS on it. If I do will post what they tell me.